# Can a 38kHz IR receiver module (TSOP38238) decode 870Hz pulse modulation IR?

Tags: arduino, infrared

I'm trying to reverse engineer my A/C remote controller IR.

I've decoded the IR signal as a NEC code with the [PJRC IRremote](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_IRremote.html) library.
My attempt to retransmit the same code to A/C unit was unsuccessful.

Having a look at the IR code with a logic analyser (with an IR sensor rather than the TSOP38238) revealed the remote uses 870Hz [pulse modulation](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN3053.pdf).

How could the TSOP38238 decode that signal? is the decoding reliable?
Is this really a NEC variant with a different modulation?

EDIT: The module isn't a TSOP38238, but something that looks like it with the same pinout (should be compatible). The caption says `084ST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you worry too much about (in)compatibilities. My guess is that you can just use that TSOP38238 and that it will receive the 870 Hz pulses flawlessly.

To make sending and receiving IR codes more reliable, the sender does not send 870 Hz pulses. Instead when a "1" needs to be sent it sends a 38 kHz signal, when a "0" needs to be sent it sends nothing. This is simple amplitude modulation and the TSOP38238 can decode that, the 870 Hz pulses will reappear at it's output.

Just feed those to your Arduino so that it can decode the 870 Hz pulses into codes.

So no worries, just try it and it will work !

Comment: seems like you are right. I've compared the output of the TSOP vs an IR sensor captured with a logic analyser, the TSOP changes the length a bit, but it seems like it's decoded properly! [Here's](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09786574739607668299) the capture if you're interested. It's formatted with [Saleae Logic](https://www.saleae.com/downloads) file format.

Comment: Told you so , enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

> How could the TSOP38238 decode that signal?

All the TSOP38238 will do is decode a 38kHz IR carrier signal.  What your A/C remote is likely doing (and what the A/C unit is expecting to see) is sending that pulse-modulated signal you saw on your logic analyzer with the logic high portions sent on a 38kHz carrier wave.

> Is this really a NEC variant with a different modulation?

From what you described, yes, everything seems to hold up as the NEC protocol.  Check [this](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/FPGA/NEC+Infrared+Transmission+Protocol) out for more details on the NEC protocol.

Comment: see the capture file linked in my comment to the accepted answer. It wasn't the case, the TSOP just passes those signals over.

Comment: The TSOP38238 is definitely decoding a 38kHz signal.  If the TSOP38238 is not seeing an IR signal with a ~38kHz carrier, it will not generate any output at all!

Comment: Per figure 5 in the [device spec](http://www.vishay.com/docs/82491/tsop382.pdf), the carrier has to be within +/- 10% of 38kHz in order to drive output from the part.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been mislead about the model of the IR module. The confusion was because of the form factor & pinout. Just had a look on the module and it seems like the caption is `084ST`, which I couldn't find the datasheet for. I'll also edit the question